# multi lingual support in umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco5, umbraco-blog

I did create a website in Umbraco. The website is in **English** .

My English website contains only HTML coding and .net user controls.

Now I did add one more language **poland** and managed corresponding host names .

How can I use the same HTML pages and .net user controls to **polish** without creating **duplicate templates and datatypes**

Answer (score 1):

We had same earlier we had site in English and then we created new following structure of it. by making little change.

```
Root
--- Website
----- Home
----- Products
----- Details..
```

then what we did its little bit change into node structure of it.

```
Root
--- English
------ Home
------ Products
------ Details..

--- Polish
------ Home
------ Products
------ Details..
```

so there will be let `XSLT` and `Razor` changes
if you have nay more question please do let me know.

Comment: I did all these things my question is without recreating any tempaltes for polish site can I use the same template and translate to polish

Comment: yes, you can use same node structure for that and you can use that, what you have to do is in polish site you have to have polish language content that sit. you don't have to create anything new.

Answer (score 1):

I would also add that, because in most cases you are sharing templates and macros for all language variants, you will want to translate and format the text in them based on the appropriate culture setting (for example, if you have, let's say, a newslist displaying the latest 5 news items, their date and authors, you will want the 'author' word to display in the correct language).

This is where dictionary items come in. [This video](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/umbraco-fundamentals/running-multiple-sites/templates,-dictionary-items-and-recursive-values) should provide more information, if you have an Umbraco TV subscription. If not, [here](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/umbraco-help/settings/editdictionaryitem) is a text-only explanation to get you started.